# How to derive $u^Tu\cdot v-v^Tu\cdot u$

Tags: vectors, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3175876/734608), the author states that
$u_\bot = u^Tu\cdot v-v^Tu\cdot u$ is perpendicular to $u$ if $v$ not parallel to $u$. This seems derived from the [Gram–Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), and I can indeed derive similar formulas, such as

$u_\bot = v-\operatorname{proj}_uv=v-\frac{v \cdot u}{u \cdot u}u$

which seems to work fine. However, while I can get close to $u^Tu\cdot v-v^Tu\cdot u$, I'm not getting there exactly. Even with this formula I have some doubts, for example, what operator has precedence? Regular multiplication or the dot product?

So the question is, how to derive $u_\bot = u^Tu\cdot v-v^Tu\cdot u$?

Comment: Multiply your expression by $u\cdot u$, and note that $u^Tu=u\cdot u$.

Comment: Hi @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, thanks, I did that previously, but the resulting expression, $(u^Tu) \cdot v - (v^Tu) \cdot u$, is not exactly what I posted in the question.

Comment: If you multiply both sides by $u\cdot u$ you get $(u\cdot u) u_{\perp} = (u\cdot u)v- (v\cdot u)u$ but $u\cdot u = u^{T}u$ and $v\cdot u = v^{T}u$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, my issue is that this makes the dot product irrelevant: it becomes a regular scalar * vector multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the equation $ u^Tu\cdot v-v^Tu \cdot u $ the operation «$ \cdot $» is regular multiplication. I recommend using the notation «$ \cdot $» for the dot product and writing the equation better like this: $ (u \cdot u) v- (v \cdot u) u $. Then in the formula you have for the Gramm-Schmidt process, you can multiply by $ u \cdot u $ and you get that $ (u \cdot u) u _ {\perp} = (u \cdot u) v- (v \cdot u ) u $. Since $ (u \cdot u) $ is a scalar, so $ (u \cdot u) v- (v \cdot u) u $ is a vector perpendicular to $u$ if $v$ not parallel to $u$. Remember that $v^{\top}u = v\cdot u$.

Comment: Thank you, this was my issue: the dot product becomes a regular multiplication and it was confusing me.